# Xamarin PCL HttpClient throws WebException: Error: ConnectFailure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

We're using the Mono HttpClient to send and receive data from our app. All works well except occasionally when the HttpClient throws the following exception:

```
[WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (interrupted)]
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x1004d0c80 + 0x00180> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) <0x1001dbe80 + 0x0005b> in <filename unknown>
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x10017d2b0 + 0x00028> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c7b0 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c700 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c6a0 + 0x00047> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10017cdf0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () <0x100a4f070 + 0x00e53> in <filename unknown>
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x10017d2b0 + 0x00028> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c7b0 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c700 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x10017c6a0 + 0x00047> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x10017cdf0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () <0x100a4de70 + 0x00373> in <filename unknown>
 Message: [SocketException: interrupted]
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) <0x1004b0600 + 0x00170> in <filename unknown>
 at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) <0x1004e1e90 + 0x0044b> in <filename unknown>
```

Clearly there is no connection or the connection is being lost but what's strange is that all the code that sends or receives data from the api is wrapped in try/catch so this exception must be being thrown from somewhere else - anyone have any idea where?

Here's the HttpClient code:

```
   private async Task<Result<T>> GetAsync<T>(string request)
    {
        using (var _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI);
            Debug.WriteLine(_client.BaseAddress + request);
            try
            {
              var result = await _client.GetAsync(request).WithTimeout().ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result<T>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else return new Result<T>(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed, default(T));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new Result<T>(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed, default(T));
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<Result> GetAsync(string request)
    {
        using (var _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI);
            Debug.WriteLine(_client.BaseAddress + request);
            try
            {
                var result = await _client.GetAsync(request).WithTimeout().ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<Result<TResponse>> PostObjectAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(string request, TRequest body)
    {
        using (var _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI);
            try
            {
              var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<TRequest>(request, body).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result<TResponse>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else return new Result<TResponse>(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed, default(TResponse));
            }
            catch
            {
                return new Result<TResponse>(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed, default(TResponse));
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<Result> PostObjectAsync<T>(string request, T body)
    {
        using (var _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI);
            Debug.WriteLine(_client.BaseAddress + request);
            try
            {
                var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(request, body).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<Result> PostDataAsync(string request, byte[] data, string contentType)
    {

        using (var _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var name = "";
            var fileName = "";

            switch (contentType)
            {
                case "image/jpeg":
                    name = "image";
                    fileName = "image.jpg";
                    break;

                case "audio/aac":
                    name = "audio";
                    fileName = "audio.aac";
                    break;
            }

            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BASE_URI);
            Debug.WriteLine(_client.BaseAddress + request);
            var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload-----" + ticks);
            var dataContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            dataContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(contentType);
            content.Add(dataContent, name, fileName);

            try
            {
                var result = await _client.PostAsync(request, content).WithTimeout(80000).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new Result(ResponseStatusCode.ProcessFailed);
            }
        }
    }
```

We're also using [ModernHttpClient](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) hence the NativeMessageHandler